# Performing operations inside a groupby

Tags: python, pandas

I have a groupby where the vertical axis is a account status, "Good" and "Bad" accounts, and the horizontal axis is State (AK,AZ...etc.) I want to find ratio between good and bad accounts by state but I can't find how to operate on one category ("Good") over another("Bad").

Thank you!

More details:

```
Data(contained in "df"):
astatus   astate
Good     AK
Bad      AK
Good     NY
Good     GA
```

My attempt:

```
d=df.groupby([astatus', 'astate']).size()
d=d.unstack('astate')
```

Results in:

```
astate        AK    NY   GA
astatus
Good          1     1    1
Bad           1     0    0
```

I see that there appears to be a trend in the dataset so I would like to figure out the % of good accounts by state but I'm not sure what the next step is.

Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide a bit more information on your data structure. A small testing example would also be very helpful. Otherwise, it's hard to help you properly.
As a general idea, you can use `apply` on your grouped data to take compute the ratio for each state:`sum(bads)/sum(goods)`

But again, without having more details, it's hard to advice anything definite.

Comment: If I understand correctly, the states can have unlimited amounts of "bads" and "goods", right? Since I don't have access to your data, I can test the idea that I have, so it probably won't wrong, but try `df.groupby("astatus").apply((lambda x: (sum(x=='good')/sum(x=="bad"))))`. If you provide a small dataset, I will give it another try.